# How to setup Docker + PhpStorm + xdebug on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

My problem is that xdebug doesn't work when I start listening port. I think PhpStorm can't link with xdebug. I just get debugger panel variables are not available. It's looks like xdebug have not correct settings.

Software and versions used:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Docker v 17.06
docker-compose 1.15
```

So I was trying many times setup xdebug + Docker + PhpStorm but cannot do it. I've read many tutorials but nothing haven't helped me.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - "./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "./etc/ssl:/etc/ssl"
            - "./project:/var/www/html/project"
        depends_on:
            - php
            - db

    php:
        image: nanoninja/php-fpm
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - "./etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
            - "./project:/var/www/html/project"
    db:
        image: mysql
        container_name: ${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: on-failure
        env_file:
            - ".env"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        command: mysqld --sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
        ports:
            - "8988:3306"
        volumes:
            - "./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

My `xdebug.ini` is:

```
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
```

PhpStorm settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about you describe what your problem is first

Comment: See if this helps http://tarunlalwani.com/post/debugging-php-xdebug-docker/

Comment: 1) Collect xdebug logs for such unsuccessful debug session and share it -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log 2) Why `xdebug.remote_host=localhost` if you are running it in Docker? It must be an IP of the computer where PhpStorm is running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out solution how to run xdebug.

1) First of we need create a new static route that will based on your network device. For create new static route: run in terminal `ifconfig`

and found out the exists network device. In my situation name of device  will be as

`wlp4s0`

[image]

2) Go ahead. Let's begin create the static route. In terminal run command like this:

```
> sudo ip addr add 10.254.254.254/24 brd + dev wlp4s0 label wlp4s0:1
```

3) Now if you run again `ifconfig` you'll see new static route:
[image]

4) Update

```
xdebug.ini
```

file add:

```
xdebug.remote_host=10.254.254.254
```

5) Update `docker.compose.yml` file:
in `php` section add:

```
environment:
    PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=project-docker"
    PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1
    XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=10.254.254.254
```

6) The last thing is update phpstorm settings.

Server settings:
 [image: phpstorm settings]
Remote debug config:
 [image: phpstorm settings]
7) And profit xdebug is working:
 [image: xdebug is working]

Comment: Do you **actually** have DBGp Proxy installed and running? It's a separate thing that you need to install and configure separately. If you don't (which is used very rarely .. and simply not required for a local single dev work) -- then please remove that part to avoid confusion/misleading other users with similar issues.

Comment: Yes. You were right. DBGP Proxy I haven't installed proxy.

Answer (score 11):

Docker on Linux allows Xdebug to automatically connect back to the host system so you can just set `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` and leave out the `xdebug.remote_host` in your `xdebug.ini`.

Comment: That's a very usefull solution! Worked for me on a Mint 20. Thank you!

Comment: man you just saved my life after loosing hours trying to make it work on Ubuntu, worked like a charm, tk you so muchh!!