# Debug Symfony CLI application with PhpStorm inside Docker container

Tags: php, symfony, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

My current setup involve PhpStorm IDE in which I have imported Symfony 3 projects which is basically CLI tool. On the host machine I don't have PHP installed so I'm running the application from Docker container which has PHP and Xdebug installed.

I don't have issues to debug web applications from Docker containers but with Symfony and this CLI tool it seems a little bit more tricky.

My question is how to properly set this up and debug it from PhpStorm? I tried to create a new debug configuration (PHP Remote Debug) but breakpoints are not trigged.

Comment: Why do you try to create a "PHP Remote Debug" configuration if you are telling that it's a CLI tool? You should create PHP Remote Interpreter and use "PHP Script" type of configuration .. which is for running/debugging CLI scripts (so that IDE will execute it in that Docker container).

Comment: I managed to trigger properly the debugger but now I have issue with timezone `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.` I can confirm on 1000% that php.ini has timezone properly set and php -i shows that it is loaded.

Comment: Okay I solved it by passing the timezone as -d option (configured it in phpstorm interpreter options) but it is still really strange as my php.ini contains this settings. It seems like it is totally ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppossing you have followed into the instructions mentioned into the following links:

- [Can't connect PhpStorm with xdebug with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284905/cant-connect-phpstorm-with-xdebug-with-docker/47450391#47450391)
- [How to setup Docker + PhpStorm + xdebug on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263043/how-to-setup-docker-phpstorm-xdebug-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Or similar questions

Then you need to follow theese steps:

**Step1:**
Get shell access to your container via running:

```
docker exec -ti ^container_id^ /bin/sh
```

Or if running a debian/ubuntu based one (or you installed manually `bash`):

```
docker exec -ti ^container_id^ /bin/bash
```

The `^container_id^` can be found via `docker ps` command it is the first column of the table. If running on a small window just pipe int into `less -S` resulting the command:

```
docker ps | less -S
```

Then export the following enviromental variables:

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=0.0.0.0:5092"
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

Please keep in mind to setup the correct value specified into `Servers` section as you see in the image:

[image: Phpstorm settings]

It is important in order not to run into the problem specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977304/docker-phpstorm-xdebug-cant-find-source-position-error) question.

Then just enable debugger listentin into the phpstorm and spawn the cli as you do when you run a symfony application.

Comment: Only worked for me with configuration:
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=hello". In PHPStorm host: localhost and port 80.