# Can't connect PhpStorm with xdebug with Docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
 FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine

RUN  apk add --update --virtual build_deps gcc g++ autoconf make &&\
  docker-php-source extract &&\
  pecl install xdebug &&\
  echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_mode = req" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  docker-php-ext-enable xdebug &&\
  docker-php-source delete && \
  apk del build_deps && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
  rm -rf /tmp/*

ENTRYPOINT ["php-fpm"]
```

And I run it with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx_dev:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "5092:5092"
    links:
      - "my_symfony_www_dev"
    volumes:
      - './conf/nginx/nginx_dev.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
      - './logs/dev:/var/logs'
    volumes_from:
      - 'my_symfony_www_dev'

    my_symfony_www_dev:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile_dev
      image: "myimage/my_symfony_app:dev_php"  
      volumes:
        - "$SOURCE_PATH:/var/www/html:Z"
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG= "serverName=my_symfony_www_dev"
        - XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=10.254.254.254,remote_port=9080"
        - PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED=1
```

Also as seen [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263043/how-to-setup-docker-phpstorm-xdebug-on-ubuntu-16-04) I run:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.254.254.254/24 brd + dev enp4s0 label enp4s0:1
```

And configured the PhpStorm IDE like that:

[image: Remote Debugger PhpStorm settings]

[image: Server]

[image: Xdebug Config]

[image: DBGp Proxy config]

Then in Firefox I press the [image] button and in PhpStorm I press the [image] button I set a breakpoint over the `app_dev.php` and nothing happens.

My system listens over the port `9080` via `netstat -ntlp` command where the PhpStorm listens to (PhpStorm is a server according to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8049991/4706711)).

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4773/java
```

Do you have any idea on why that happens and how to fix it?

## Edit 1:

The `phpinfo()` shows:

[image: xdebug phpinfo]

I've also set de cocker-compose.yml as:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx_dev:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "5092:5092"
    links:
      - "my_symfony_www_dev"
    volumes:
      - './conf/nginx/nginx_dev.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
      - './logs/dev:/var/logs'
    volumes_from:
      - 'my_symfony_www_dev'

    my_symfony_www_dev:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile_dev
      image: "myimage/my_symfony_app:dev_php"  
      volumes:
        - "$SOURCE_PATH:/var/www/html:Z"
      environment:
        - XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=10.254.254.254,remote_port=9080"
        - PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED=1
```

And my dockerfile is:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine

RUN  apk add --update --virtual build_deps gcc g++ autoconf make &&\
  docker-php-source extract &&\
  pecl install xdebug &&\
  echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_mode = req" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  docker-php-ext-enable xdebug &&\
  docker-php-source delete && \
  apk del build_deps && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
  rm -rf /tmp/*

ENTRYPOINT ["php-fpm"]
```

Still Same result.

Comment: 1) Collect `phpinfo()` output captured via browser (as you are trying to debug a web page) -- top header table + xdebug specific section. This is to confirm currently applied/active settings; 2) Enable and collect xdebug logs for such unsuccessful debug session; 3) You have `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` in your Dockerfile -- with this option xdebug ignores value of `xdebug.remote_host`. So far it must be wrong IP issue -- xdebug must be trying to connect but to the wrong IP (could be because of #3 for example)

Comment: 4) You have specified `serverName=my_symfony_www_dev`. In such case Host field in `PHP | Servers` should also be using it -- that's how PhpStorm identifies what Server entry to use.

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019201/phpstorm-debug-with-laravel-homestead-not-working/45019239#45019239) might help you

Comment: 1) Do not silently update the post -- nobody gets notified about that. 2) Where is xdebug log? 3) Your screenshot of xdebug info shows that your `XDEBUG_CONFIG` from docker_compose file is not getting applied, at very least in a way you were expecting it to be (port and remote_host are still using defaults).

Comment: Instead of using a breakpoint inside phpstorm, you can also use this function in your code 
````xdebug_break();````. If this triggers the debug function in phpstorm, there is probably something wrong with your path mapping

Comment: In preferences>Languages&Frameworks>PHP clicking the block on the utter right of the CLI interpreters options triggers the CLI interpreters window. If xdebug is configured right, and phpstorm can detect is, the "General" section will show de debugger name and version number. Does this show ````Debugger: Xdebug {version}````?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I had to do put the following over my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine

VOLUME /var/log/xdebug

ARG XDEBUG_HOST="172.17.0.1"
ARG XDEBUG_PORT=9021

RUN  apk add --update --virtual build_deps gcc g++ autoconf make &&\
  docker-php-source extract &&\
  pecl install xdebug &&\
  docker-php-ext-enable xdebug &&\
  && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_mode = req" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_host=${XDEBUG_HOST}" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
  echo "xdebug.remote_port=${XDEBUG_PORT}" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini &&\
  docker-php-source delete && \
  apk del build_deps && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
  rm -rf /tmp/*

ENTRYPOINT ["php-fpm"]
```

The `XDEBUG_HOST` build arg contains the ip of `docker0` network interface over GNU/Linux systems (use `ifconfig` to find out).

And over my `docker-compose.yml` I provide the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx_dev:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "5092:5092"
    links:
      - "my_symfony_www_dev"
    volumes:
      - './conf/nginx/nginx_dev.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
      - './logs/dev:/var/logs'
    volumes_from:
      - 'my_symfony_www_dev'

    my_symfony_www_dev:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile_dev
        args:
          XDEBUG_HOST: 172.17.0.1
          XDEBUG_PORT: 9021
      image: "myimage/my_symfony_app:dev_php"  
      volumes:
        - "$SOURCE_PATH:/var/www/html:Z"
```

Over the `./conf/nginx/nginx_dev.conf` mapped over the volume I put the following setting on `server` section:

```
server_name 0.0.0.0;
```

Then on phpstorm use the following settings:

[image: Setting Servers over phpstorm]

[image: XDEBUG settings over phpstorm]

Then you are good to go!