# Docker, PhpStorm & Xdebug: Can't find source position error

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I built an image that is based on a `php:5.6-fpm-alpine` image and I run a symfony-based application therefore I run both cli and web-based php scripts.

So I spawned a shell over my running container via:

```
docker exec -ti ^container_id^ /bin/sh
```

And over the shell I exported the following enviromental variables:

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=0.0.0.0:5092"
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

And the IDE has been setup as explained in the following links:

- [Can't connect PhpStorm with xdebug with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284905/cant-connect-phpstorm-with-xdebug-with-docker/47450391#47450391)
- [How to setup Docker + PhpStorm + xdebug on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263043/how-to-setup-docker-phpstorm-xdebug-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But when I enable the Xdebug on phpstorm even it debugs normally I get the following error message:

[image: Error displayed into my PHPSTORM running instance]

Do you know why that happens.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

That happend because on `Servers` section of the phpstorm does not have the very same name as defined in the `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` enviromental variable in order to solve that follow these steps:

**Step 1:**
Go to server settings by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`S` or by visiting File -> Settings from the menu.

**Step 2:**
Then on the open window go to Settings -> Languages & Framework -> Servers.

**Step 3:**
Set the `Name` as the one defined into:

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=0.0.0.0:5092"
```

In order to work it should be `0.0.0.0:5092` as the image shows:

[image: Server Setting here]

Comment: Thank you!  The only thing that is a bit confusing is that it should state that Name should equal the servername that is being exported.  By looking at the example it seems that any name can be used.  I tried hello and failed.  Once I added the ip and port it worked.

Comment: I have the same problem, but, when I try to save, phpstorm says that "sarver name is not specified or invalid" and I can't save it. Also, my debug is working, but not stops on breaking points, does anyone know the reason?

Comment: I only figure out when the Name need to be same and must with the post number as well.

Comment: I just figured out the "server name is not specified or invalid"... There's another entry in your servers list that is blank, delete it and that problem goes away.